# error occurs as call to non-static member function without an object argument

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, dynamic

I am trying to create an app related to Dynamic Arrays. I am trying to get instance calling a function for my array but its giving me the error:

> error: call to non-static member function without an object argument

Is there something wrong with the type of **getInstance()** function?

Here is my header and main file:

**dynamic_array.h**

```
    #ifndef DYNAMIC_ARRAY_H
#define DYNAMIC_ARRAY_H

template <class T>
class DynamicArray{
private:
    T *arr;
    static int instance;

public:
    int getInstance();
};

template <typename T>
int DynamicArray<T>::getInstance(){
    if(instance == 0){
        //...
    }
    return instance;
}

template <typename T>
int DynamicArray<T>::instance = 0;

#endif // DYNAMIC_ARRAY_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "dynamic_array.h"

    int main(){

    DynamicArray<int> *array = DynamicArray<int>::getInstance(); // Error occurs here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: make `getInstance` static (in the class definition)

Comment: also the function returns `int` but you try to assign it to a pointer, you will need to make a design change here.

Comment: @M.M when I tried to static I get error as ```error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘DynamicArray<int>*’ [-fpermissive]
     DynamicArray<int> *array = DynamicArray<int>::getInstance();```
                                                              ^

Comment: yes, I address that in my second comment

Comment: @M.M Should I change the types of ```getInstance``` or ```instance```

Comment: What kind of a design change I can? Any suggestion?

Comment: frankly this looks like combining two evils, singleton and not using `std::vector`, and there is no apparent reason for either of them. Is this homework? (nothing bad about homework, but that would explain a lot)

Comment: can you explain why you designed a function to return `int`, but then try to call it and assign the result to a pointer?

Comment: Yeah there is some gaps in an app code I filled many places except these ones. I f needed  I can share all. I ll add my whole code.

Comment: @M.M I edited my question. I changed the type of getInstance() and instance

Comment: imho the question was better before. Please read about [mcve], before all code that was necessary to see why you get the error was included in your question, now there is lots of code that is irrelevant for your particular question

Comment: in any case, all the code does not explain why you declared the method to return an `int` and then want to assign its return value to a `int*`. Its wrong, and not clear why you did it. Can you use `std::vector` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 vector type for instance?

Comment: dynamic arrays are called [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in C++

Comment: @idclev463035818 can you show me as answer to fix my error for this small piece of code as an answer. I ll acept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: you already got the answer with the very first comment

Comment: @idclev463035818 I ll try to search but couldnt understand. Thanks!!1

Comment: ...but this will only fix the immediate error, to fix your code, you need to explain what and why are you doing. Why are you not using `std::vector` ?  Why is the member `instance` an `int` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 if I use vector, inside of if statement ```instance == 0``` given to me so I thought type of instance should be int? If I type it as vector, I cant change inside of if statement.

Comment: is this homework? what was given to you?

Comment: @idclev463035818 For this piece of code, main.cpp is no changement, its same as shown. The gaps are: ```... instance;```  ```... getInstance();```  ```...::getInstance(){``` 
 ```...::instance = 0;```  I need to fill ... gaps which are in header file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to implement design pattern Singleton and a vector (kind of dynamic array) at once.

What about this:

*dynamic_array.h*

```
#ifndef DYNAMIC_ARRAY_H
#define DYNAMIC_ARRAY_H

#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class DynamicArray
{
private:
    static DynamicArray* instance;
    T* arr;

    /* singleton pattern
        forbid outside access to constructor */

    DynamicArray();
    DynamicArray(size_t size_of_array);
    ~DynamicArray();

public:
    static void createInstance(size_t size_of_array);
    static DynamicArray<T>* getInstance();
    static void destroyInstance();
};

template <class T>
DynamicArray<T>* DynamicArray<T>::instance = nullptr;

// singleton methods

template<class T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::createInstance(size_t size_of_array)
{
    if (instance) return;
    instance = new DynamicArray(size_of_array);
}

template <typename T>
DynamicArray<T>* DynamicArray<T>::getInstance()
{
    // might be nullptr if not initialized

    return instance;
}

template<class T>
inline void DynamicArray<T>::destroyInstance()
{
    // delete check for nullptr on its own

    delete instance;
}

// constructor

template<class T>
inline DynamicArray<T>::DynamicArray(size_t size_of_array)
{
    std::cout << "DynamicArray's been constructed.\n";
    arr = new T[size_of_array];
}

// destructor

template<class T>
inline DynamicArray<T>::~DynamicArray()
{
    delete[] arr;
    std::cout << "DynamicArray's destructor has been called.\n";

    // instance is still alive
}

#endif
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "dynamic_array.h"

int main()
{
    DynamicArray<int>::createInstance(10);
    DynamicArray<int>* instance = DynamicArray<int>::getInstance();

    // do something with instance

    /* manually call destructor, 
    so that if more pointers are pointing to instance
    they have no access to a delete call */

    DynamicArray<int>::destroyInstance();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If in my if condition(instance == 0), how can I assign something to instance as int?

Comment: Well, you might want to post your entire specification because I don't understand. If you mean `nullptr` (pointer version of zero), then check for `nullptr` instead. C++ is a typed language, you can't just assign `int` type to a variable of `DynamicArray<int>*`. Unless you want to change the underlying array `T*`.